# Achieving interface without inheritance in Python

Tags: python, python-typing, pylance

I have a sorted linked list

```py
class SortedLinkedList:
    # ...
    def insert(self, value: int):
        # ...
        if node.value > value:
            self.add_before(node, value)
        # ...
```

I would like to generalize the type of values that a `Node` can hold from only `int`s to any object that overloads the `>` operator by implementing the `__gt__()` magic method.

In other languages I would achieve this by using an `Interface`, but Python apparently has no analog. I've seen suggestions to fake interfaces by using abstract classes like

```py
class Sortable(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __gt__(self, other) -> bool:
        pass

class SortedLinkedList:
    # ...
    def insert(self, value: Sortable, node: Node):
        # ...
```

The problem is this approach requires extending and using subclasses from `Sortable`, which means types that already have `>` functionality like integers cannot be used

```py
linkedlist.insert(5) # Pylance red squiggles
```

```
Argument of type "Literal[5]" cannot be assigned to
parameter "value" of type "Sortable" in function "insert"
  "Literal[5]" is incompatible with "Sortable" Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

I understand that Interfaces are not necessary pre-runtime given Python's dynamic duck typing and implicit style. I am not a fan, and am opting to use available tooling like [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) and [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) to achieve a strictly typed developer experience.

I am also not looking to use runtime checks like `.hasattr(value, '__gt__')`. I'm wanting this to register on the type system/language server/IDE level, as expressivity, readability, and IDE intellisense are the main benefits of strict typing.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol).

```py
class Sortable(Protocol):
    def __gt__(self, other) -> bool: ...
```

With this, any class that defines `__gt__` will be detected as an implicit subtype of `Sortable`. Note that in Pythons >= 3.8, you may need to to make `other` positional:

```py
class Sortable(Protocol):
    def __gt__(self, other, /) -> bool: ...
```

This is because type checkers might not handle dunder-methods like `__gt__` any different from a normal method and thus expects that the arguments might need to be callable by keyword. Adding the `/` tells the checkers that `__gt__`'s arguments won't ever need to be passed by keyword. Conversely, if an argument will only be passed by keyword, mark the protocol's method accordingly:

```py
class Something(Protocol):
    def method(self, *, name) -> str: ...
```

Comment: Protocol is the way to go type checking wise: it is worth mentioning that otherwise - i.e. in a project that won't use static type checking one may go about just using the `<` operator anyway and just let bad uses raise error on runtime.

Comment: Otherwise, for issubclass testing, Python had the figure of Virtual subclassing - classes inheritng from abc.ABC have a ".register" class that can do what the O.P. wants.